# How to use group by date when dates fields are different?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have for tables:

1. **documents**: docId, tsCreatedBy, tsCreateDate
2. **nispah**: nispahId, tsCreatedBy, tsCreateDate
3. **hozactions**: actId, tsCreatedBy, tsCreateDate
4. **vwemployee**: id, fullName

I want to show number of documents, nispah and hozactions for a specific user id on a specific range of dates, group by date.
Something like:

1. Row1: date1, number of documents, number of nispah, number of hozactions
2. Row2: date2, number of documents, number of nispah, number of hozactions
3. Row3: date3.....

How can i group by date when i have different dates in every table?

Comment: Join the tables on tsCreatedDate and tsCreatedBy and apply aggregations as needed? Or maybe I'm missing something. Can you describe the problem in more detail.

Comment: @jpw
I tried to join the tables with inner join on tsCreatedBy , but I can't inner join tsCreateDate because it can be different in every Table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit of guessing here, but I think that what you need to do is to generate a set of all the dates and do a cross join with the users, and then left join the other tables on the employee.ID.

Maybe this is what you want:

```
select 
    dates.tscreatedate
    , count(distinct d.docid) number_of_documents 
    , count(distinct n.nispahid) number_of_nispah
    , count(distinct h.actid) number_of_hozactions
from 
    vwemployee e
cross join 
    (
       select cast(tscreatedate as date) tscreatedate from documents
       union all
       select cast(tscreatedate as date) tscreatedate from nispah
       union all
       select cast(tscreatedate as date) tscreatedate from hozactions
    ) dates
left join 
    documents d on e.id = d.tscreatedby 
               and cast(d.tscreatedate as date) = dates.tscreatedate
left join 
    nispah n on e.id = n.tscreatedby 
            and cast(n.tscreatedate as date) = dates.tscreatedate
left join 
    hozactions h on e.id = h.tscreatedby 
                and cast(h.tscreatedate as date) = dates.tscreatedate
where 
    e.id = 1
group by 
    dates.tscreatedate
```

Or maybe I totally misunderstood, and if so I'll remove this answer.

Comment: You kind of understood :)
It's good but it doesn't group by date.
I get the same date (with different hours). How can i group it?

Comment: @HilaGal Oh, I guess the dates are really `datetime` which includes a time component. You can "fix" this by casting the datetime to date like this: `cast(tsCreatedDate as date)` . You should probably do it in all places where tsCreatedDate is referenced.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem :)